# Прикрепить заголовок к левому краю при горизонтальном скроле

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно сделать так, чтобы при горизонтальном скроле, заголовки(выделенные жирным) оставались всегда по левую сторону блока.Нужно сделать на чистом JS или на TS. Использовал scrollLeft, но не помогло, либо что-то сделал неправильно)
Пример на фото.Также добавляю линк на этот пример,смотреть надо на малых экранах)https://www.coolblue.nl/en/compare/831904/823982/827526/831891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял, что именно вы хотите.
Но если вам необходимо чтобы заголовки всегда располагались только слева не вылезая за рамки строки таблицы, то вы можете использовать At-правило @media  с уменьшением шрифта. Я заметил что у вас сайт адаптивен и при уменьшении размера экрана (типа как у iphone) размер шрифта во всей таблице уменьшается, так и в этом ситуации вы можете проделать тоже самое для каждого нужного размера
**что то типа**

```css
(@media screen and (max-width:1300px){
.comparison-list__title is-absolute {
    font-size: ...px;
}
```

либо задать строке

```css
overwlow-y: scroll;
```

Но честно говоря я даже не понимаю для чего конкретно вы хотите это сделать и что хотите получить в итоге...

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что весь блок мы можем скролить вправо, но все заголовки таблицы остаются прижаты к левому краю. Это не мой сайт, на который я оставил ссылку, это просто пример, как нужно сделать)Чтобы увидеть пример, нужно сайт посмотреть на экране от 500px и меньше, соответственно, проскролив его по оси "X"

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит скинуть конкретный пример с кодом и тогда я попытаюсь помочь.

Comment: Проблема уже решена, спасибо)